# Xcode font disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts

I imported my fonts on my project (Roboto), it worked with my first ViewController, but now Roboto disappeared of my Custom Fonts. Now when I want to modify my font, the font changed to Helvetica.

I don't understand how it happened, I didn't change the fonts folder.

Comment: What do you mean disappeared? Do you mean it's not selectable from the Storyboard? Have you tried loading it in code instead of the storyboard?

Comment: I'd try removing it from your project completely. importing it again. And making sure it's added to the info-plist. with both your project and project.test as targets. If that doesn't work, do a project clean, delete your Derived-data folder and restart Xcode

Comment: You're the man user100002, I just re-importing and it works, thanks a lot

Comment: Write it as an aswer I will mark it as done, thanks again

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, also using Roboto. After restarting Xcode the font reappeared.

Answer (score 7):

No need to reinstall the font, since it's already added to the project. Just quit Xcode and delete DerivedData then start Xcode again. The custom font should be ok.
I delete the whole DerivedData folder, since Xcode will generate it automatically.

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the custom font on one of your UILabel through the storyboard, after that search for the custom font programatically:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
        {
            print("\(family)")
            for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
            {
                print("== \(names)")
            }
        }
```

You should be able to see the font you are looking for