# Font missing after upgrade to Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have a strange bug in Xocde. After upgrading to El Capitan and Xcode 7.2 the font I had used for my app (Superclarendon) disappeared. When I want to edit the text, it shows System. And then when switching to Custom, it shows all other fonts, but not the one I need. Any idea how to fix this and retrieve the font?

Comment: It seems to be missing from my system, too, but I can't find any reports about this happening. You can re-install it, but your users may not have it.

Comment: @john elemans: did reinstalling work for you?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? The font is still available in other programs. Just missing in Xcode. Even in new projects.

Comment: possible duplicate with [Xcode font disappeared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289378/xcode-font-disappeared/36179655#36179655)

Comment: You can remove the DerivedData folder, then open the Xcode, font should be ok.

Comment: @chancyWu Thanks mate, will try!